# grammar of "keep your seat belt fastened while seated"

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, reference

I understand the meaning of the phrase "keep your seat belt fastened while seated" which you can see in the aeroplane written on the front seat. 
  
 But I absolutely can't figure out the grammar of the phrase, of the part "while seated". 
 
 Can anyone explain why this form of verb is used? Doesn't it sound strange to a native speaker? 
 
As far as I understand there are several things in this phrase that confuse me:

1. **Subject** :  If the subject is missed in the last verb (to seat), it should be the same subject as in case of the first verb (to keep) or of the second verb (to fasten). But *to seat* is a causative verb, so it's not true.
2. **Voice** :  It seems to be active, but it should be passive.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's a shortened version of *[**to be**] seated*, which is semantically passive/stative (not "causative", as in *They seated me at the back*). And the subject of both clauses is implied ***you keep*** (imperative) and *while **you are** seated*.

Comment: It's an imperative statement, so there's an implied "You" at the start.  References claim that "while" is a conjunction in this context, though I've never really thought that through.

Comment: @FumbleFingers but does this sound correctly for you? Is it OK to miss auxiliary verb? Can I say "The house built in 1965" meaning "the house was built in 1965"?

Comment: Most questions here are from non-native speakers. This is a grammatical short form of _Keep your seatbelt fastened while **you are** seated._ It follows the grammar rules for signs, which are different from speech. The second _you_ is deleted under identity with _your_, and the _are_ is deleted because it's predictable -- it just announces that _seated_ is a predicate adjective in the present tense, unneeded information. Predictability in signs is low; they are supposed to convey vital information very efficiently with very few words.

Comment: @JohnLawler thanks a lot for your answer. Can you recommend me where can I learn about grammar rules for signs? I tried to find in google but didn't succeed.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I understand the difference between NP and sentense. I tried to form a sentence in analogy to sentence "keep your seatbelt fastened while seated" - while seated is not NP here. Thanks for the link to Enlish language Learners!

Comment: @KseniaK, the grammar rules for signs have a lot in common with those for newspaper headlines. If you google **headline grammar rules** you will find several articles like this one: http://www.englishlessonsbrighton.co.uk/8-grammar-rules-writing-newspaper-headlines/

Comment: @FumbleFingers is correct. It's "sign-speak" if you will. Signs and notices commonly drop words that aren't completely necessary or that can be assumed to save space and simplify their message.

Answer (score 1):

This is a grammatical short form of

> Keep your seatbelt fastened while *you are* seated.

It follows the grammar rules for signs, which are different from speech. The second *you* is deleted under identity with your, and the *are* is deleted because it's predictable–it just announces that seated is a predicate adjective in the present tense, unneeded information.

–John Lawler

"The  grammar rules for signs have a lot in common with those for newspaper headlines. If you google [headline grammar rules](https://www.google.com/search?q=headline%20grammar%20rules) you will find several articles like this one:   englishlessonsbrighton.co.uk/ "

–JavaLatte

Comment: And we can say "While seated, keep your seatbelt fastened." or even "You, while you are seated, you keep your seatbelt fastened, do you hear me?"

Comment: "it just announces that seated is a predicate adjective in the present tense, unneeded information." - I don't quite get it. Why do you call it 'unneeded information'? In this case it is a marker of passive voice, isn't it? And if we remove itб it's no more obvious whether it is a predicate adjective or a past tense of a verb.